# Vimeo embedded player doesn't work on Android devices

Tags: android, vimeo

I use the following code for embedding video on the webpage:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/"video ID"?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=fd735b" width="940" height="529" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It works great on desktop and Apple devices. But on the Android devices, when I click play button loading circle appears and after video jumps to the end.

I made tests with Genymotion emulator. Could it be cause of the problem?
I tested on Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.1.1) and on tablet (4.2.2).

Can you give any advice?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just need to enable conversion to mobile formats:

> Go to My Settings and select the "Videos" tab. From there check the box next to "Make my videos compatible with mobile devices" and click the Save as default button. Check "Also, apply to existing videos" to do just that.

http://vimeo.com/help/faq/mobile-apps/mobile-videos

Comment: 2022, this option no longer appears to exist.